# $_SESSION not working inside postgres query

Tags: php, postgresql, session, pg-query

after everything to fix it, I have no more ideas and came here to find some help.

My $_SESSION isn't working inside an SELECT of postgres, but when I put like this it's OK:

> The genre you selected is: `<?php echo $_SESSION[genero];?>`.

But inside my pg_query, it doesn't work and I know it is the $_SESSION because if I change de $_SESSION for it's value it's OK. Anybody that knows how to answer this question?

EDIT: tried put the value by $_GET and still the same problem. I don't know why it's happening, because I already did this before once... And both GET and SESSION shows the value if echo them.

Comment: Can you show us the query?

Comment: He's talking about [his earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294345/how-to-intersect-datas-from-tables-on-postgres).

Comment: In your query try: '$_SESSION[\'genero\']'

Comment: Update the question with your DB usage.

Comment: This is the query:

$result1 = pg_query("SELECT title, movieid FROM movies
WHERE movieid in (
        SELECT movieid FROM ratings
        WHERE votes > 0
    INTERSECT 
        SELECT movieid FROM genres 
        WHERE genre = '$_SESSION[genero]')");

Answer (score 0):

Guessing since you didn't actually show you code, but: You're almost certainly using single-quoted strings and expecting string interpolation to work, e.g.

```
pg_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sess = $_SESSION');
```

or

```
$dbh->exec('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sess = $_SESSION')
```

If so: [string interpolation in PHP is performed only on double-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). More importantly though, don't use string interpolation in SQL unless you're *absolutely sure* the value can't be set or changed by the user. Even then, preferably don't. Use parameterized queries, e.g.

```
pg_query_params('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sess = $1', array($_SESSION));
```

or

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sess = :sess');
$stmt->bindParam(':sess', $_SESSION);
$stmt->execute();
```

See:

- [PHP SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
- [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which is how you *should* be connecting to the database if you aren't already.

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva 'didn't work' isn't an error message. What exactly happened, when you ran exactly what code?

Comment: I think that the first one (pg_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sess = $_SESSION');) would match my problem, but nothing happened. In other words: the problem goes on. If I change the SESSION for it's value, like Action, for example, it works. The only thing I don't know is why the SESSIN isn't working here...

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva "nothing happens". Do you check for errors? Is there no error but zero results? If so, is there actually a corresponding row in the table?

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva Also did you understand that the first two are *examples of what I think you are probably doing incorrectly in your current code*? I.e. they are *wrong* and *will not work*. Read the whole answer. Then try again with a parameterised query like the `pg_query_params` one shown

Comment: ain't no error. I just want to put the value that is in the SESSION in my query. Already did this, just don't know why, in this case, it isn't working...